# contradiction proof on divides

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

Suppose a,b ∈ Z. If 4 | $(a^2 + b^2)$ then a and b are not both odd.

So, assuming that 4 | $(a^2 + b^2)$  and $a$ and $b$ are odd

this gives $4k=(2l+1)^2+(2u+1)^2$ for some $k,l,u\in z$

eventually leading to $4k=4(l^2+l+u)+2(u^2+1)$

The RHS is not a multiple of 4 when $u=2$ contradiction.

Is this valid, thanks.

Comment: You are trying to prove the claim in the first line?  Not sure why you can set $u=2$ towards the end...isn't $u$ an unknown parameter?

Comment: As a hint;  show that $m$ odd implies $m^2=4k+1$ for some $k$.

Comment: thanks i see my mistake, should i leave the question as it is or correct it?

Comment: @CarlosBacca You asked where the mistake is. We told you where the mistake is. The logical next step is to accept one of the answers. Don't edit out your mistake.

Comment: True that would be pointless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not yet valid, because you haven't shown why the RHS cannot be a multiple of $4$. You cannot simply set $u=2$, because the $u$ you have is already determined by $b$, since $b=2u+1$.

---

To correct your proof, re-think how you got from

$$4k=(2l+1)^2 + (2u+1)^2$$

to

$$4k = 4(l^2+l+u) + 2(u^2+1)$$

because I think you were a bit sloppy here.

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid. You have done a mistake in calculation.
RHS will be $4(l^2+u^2+l+u)+2$, which is not divisible by 4.
Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply correctly, the RHS leaves a rest of 2 modulo 4. So your idea was correct, you just need to recalculate.